# Add Minus Sign in Invoice PDF Totals Block

Tags: invoice, pdf, totals

I have added a custom discount block when I print my Invoice PDF. It looks something like below

[image]

In my `config.xml`, I am using below code to add totals in PDF

```
<pdf>
            <totals>
                <mymodule translate ="title">
                    <title>Discount</title>
                    <source_field>mymodule_amount</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>650</sort_order>
                </mymodule>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
```

How can I add a `MINUS` sign in front of discounted price ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I assume the discount field comes from a custom module you wrote. It is possible to define a model under the `pdf > totals > field` section in your `config.xml`:

```
<pdf>
    <totals>
        <mymodule translate ="title">
            <title>Discount</title>
            <source_field>mymodule_amount</source_field>
            <model>mymodule/sales_pdf_discount</model>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>0</display_zero>
            <sort_order>650</sort_order>
        </mymodule>
    </totals>
</pdf>
```

<sub>Of course you also need to have a model section in your `config.xml`.</sub>

Then you can implement the model under `app/code/[code pool]/[namespace]/[module name]/Model/Sales/Pdf/Discount.php`:

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Pdf_Discount extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{

    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        // getAmount is defined in the parent class and should read
        // the value from the defined source_field in your config.xml
        $discount = $this->getAmount();
        $label = '- ' . Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Discount');        
        $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $total = array(
            'amount'    => $discount,
            'label'     => $label,
            'font_size' => $fontSize
        );
        return array($total);
    }

}
```

In general, you can have a look at the implementation under `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/*`.

Comment: How do I add `model section` for `pdf` ? And is it necessary to make a new model for just a sign ?

Comment: At least I do not think that there is any any other proper solution. The model is quite tiny, so this should not really be a problem.

Comment: I agree. I have included that minus sign elsewhere viz. order total and invoice blocks, but do you suggest specifying a minus sign in pdf as well ?

Comment: If you show it elsewhere, it also makes sense in the PDF. I think it is also semantically correct to show it. By the way please accept answers if they solve your problems (not only this one, also look at your other questions).

Comment: it says `PDF total model should extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default`

Comment: Then you did not implement/copy it correctly. My code above extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default`.

Comment: ` $discount = $this->getAmount();` is returning me null. How to fetch it ?

Comment: This means that your source field `mymodule_amount` is not defined properly and Magento cannot read the data from it. But this is indeed another problem.

Comment: `mymodule_amount` is defined in DB ?

Comment: and if it was not defined, how it was showing discount earlier ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16427/discussion-between-simon-and-jordan).

Comment: I can not login simon.

Comment: This is too long for here. Short Skype chat? simon.sprankel

Answer (score 1):

The default discount total uses `<amount_prefix>`

```
           <discount translate="title">
                <title>Discount</title>
                <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
                <amount_prefix>-</amount_prefix>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            </discount>
```

provided your custom implementation does not circumvent it in its own version of getTotalsForDisplay(), you should be able to just use

```
     <pdf>
        <totals>
            <mymodule translate ="title">
                <title>Discount</title>
                <source_field>mymodule_amount</source_field>
                <amount_prefix>-</amount_prefix>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>650</sort_order>
            </mymodule>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
```